# Make a Linux 'service' start automatically on server reboot

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, service, rhel

We have some custom container services running on RHEL EC2 instances.  Would like to know how to make these services start automatically on reboot of the instance or when I stop and start the instance?

I have a script that checks for the status of the service and start them if it's not running, but I would like to have them start automatically once the instance starts.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a service=("SERVICE_1" "SERVICE_2" "SERVICE_3")

for i in "${service[@]}"
do
        if (( $(docker ps | grep -v grep | grep $i | wc -l) > 0 ))
        then
        echo "$i is running!!!"
        else
        docker start $i
        fi
done
```

Comment: refer https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/ u mat able to get more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cloud-init, afaik - see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html#cloud-init-per) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)  - then you can create a script like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==BOUNDARY=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--==BOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/cloud-boothook; charset="us-ascii"

# Install nfs-utils
cloud-init-per once yum_update yum update -y
cloud-init-per once install_nfs_utils yum install -y nfs-utils

# Create /efs folder
cloud-init-per once mkdir_efs mkdir /efs


--==BOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
# Create jenkins_home
mkdir /tmp/test
```